# How do I add key constrains in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, constraints

I have the following *.hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.models.results">
<class name="TestResult" table="testcaseresults">
    <id name="testCaseResultsId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="testcaseresultsid">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>

    <property name="start" type="java.sql.Timestamp" column="starttime"/>
    <property name="end" type="java.sql.Timestamp" column="endtime"/>
    <property name="results" type="java.lang.String" column="results"/>
    <property name="passed" type="java.lang.Integer" column="passed"/>

    <join table="testcase">
        <key column="testcaseid"/>
        <property name="testTitle" column="testcasename"/>
        <property name="tfsid" column="tfsid"/>
    </join>
    <join table="selwowusers">
        <key column="userid"/>
        <property name="tester" column="useremail" type="java.lang.String"/>

    </join>


</class>
```

Now, my problem is that the "testcase" and "selwowusers" tables have foreign key constrains (with themselves). How exactly do I write the one-to-many properties? I'm new to hibernate and the online tutorials haven't been too descriptive.

When I run the app as it is, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table testcase add index FKBBAC26C2C073639B (testcaseid), add constraint FKBBAC26C2C073639B foreign key (testcaseid) references testcaseresults (testcaseresultsid)
Jan 23, 2012 4:08:57 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`newseleniumwowmatrix`.`#sql-6379_4868`, CONSTRAINT `FKBBAC26C2C073639B` FOREIGN KEY (`testcaseid`) REFERENCES `testcaseresults` (`testcaseresultsid`))
Jan 23, 2012 4:08:57 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure you want to have property "testTitle" in Testresult instead of referencing the testcase in testresult?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate allows you to define relationships, it cannot enforce constraints. As you might observe, it is a mapping tool to map java objects with your database tables. It is not meant for defining data model.

-JavaJigsaw.com

Comment: I know that, but why am I getting that error? It says that it has to do with constrains so I think is that I'm not letting it know that there is a constrain.

Answer (score 0):

The one-to-many can be represented as many-to-one from TestCase

<class name="Testcase" table="testcase">
 <many-to-one name="testcaseID" class="TestResult" column="testcaseid"/>